# Core Data migration - new to many relationship from existing data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have an old Core Data model "User" which has a few string attributes, let's say "name", "email", "street", "city". I need to migrate it to a new version which will have a one-to-many relationship with a new class called "Address" which will have "street" and "city" attributes.

So going from:

```
User
 - name
 - email
 - street
 - city
```

To:

```
User
 - name
 - email
 <->> Address
      - street
      - city
```

How would I achieve that? Can I do that using value expression or do I need to have a `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` class? How would it look? Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear. Do you need help on migration or relationships? Migration: http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration. Core Data Basics: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: I need help with migration - that should be clear from "I need to migrate". And no, Lightweight Migration won't help me in this case - it can only do basic stuff like adding or removing attributes, not creating new entities and relationships

Comment: Your question is perfectly clear and you will need to customise the migration. There's some info on mapping models and specifying an NSEntityMigrationPolicy [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMappingOverview.html) and the referenced [models/migration guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMigrationProcess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH6-SW4) specifically mentions your use-case.

Comment: @dominikkrejcik You might find this useful - http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-migration.html